# How to CLONE a fieldset element and append it inside a form, correctly?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-clone

[**Jsfiddle here.**](https://jsfiddle.net/Jesss/vbz0u0rf/)

This is a simple example to reproduce my problem. Basically, I have a `form` (to read in data about multiple candidates), in which I have a `fieldset` (which takes input of data for *one* candidate), and then I have a button labelled `ADD CANDIDATE`. When it is clicked, the above `fieldset` should be *cloned* and copied below the above fieldset, so that the data about another candidate can be entered.

For the first candidate, each data field in the `form` is of the form `allCandidatesArray[candidateNumber][fieldName]`, e.g. `allCandidatesArray[0][nameInput]` to facilitate the reading and further analysis of data submitted when the form is submitted. So in the Click handler/listener of `ADD CANDIDATE` button, I also do some programming to increment the `candidateNumber` in `allCandidatesArray[candidateNumber][fieldName]` when a new candidate is added.

But the main idea is to clone the previous `fieldset` and append the cloned `fieldset` below the previous `fieldset`. **The problem is that the new thing which is appended is Not a `fieldset`. It is just three `input` elements. No labels, no nothing! What was cloned was a `fieldset` containing `input`s and `label`s.**

**The question is WHY? And how do I fix this?**

```js
$(document).on("click", ".addMobileButton", function() {

 //alert(".addMobileButton clicked.");//check  

 var parentRow = $(this).closest(".row");

 var idOfThis = $(this).attr('id');
 //alert(idOfThis);//check
 //alert(idOfThis.length);//check
 var candidateNumber = idOfThis.slice(idOfThis.length-2, idOfThis.length-1);
 //alert("candidateNumber: " + candidateNumber);//check

 var nthMobileNumberOfThisCandidate = idOfThis.slice(-1);
 //alert("nthMobileNumberOfThiscandidate: " + nthMobileNumberOfThiscandidate);//check
 var newNthMobileOfThiscandidate = ++nthMobileNumberOfThisCandidate;
 //alert("newNthMobileNumberOfThisCandidate: " + newNthMobileOfThisCandidate);//check

 parentRow.after('<div id="rowAddedForCandidatesMobile" class="row valign-wrapper"><div class="input-field col l3"><input type="text" id="mobileInput'+candidateNumber+'" class="validate" name="allCandidatesArray['+candidateNumber+'][mobileInput][]"/><label for="mobileInput'+candidateNumber+'">Mobile</label></div><div class="col l1 addMobileButtonWrapper"><a id="addMobileButton'+candidateNumber+''+newNthMobileOfThisCandidate+'" class="btn-floating btn waves-light waves-effect blue white-text addMobileButton"><i class="material-icons">add</i></a></div></div>');


});







$(document).ready(function() {



 /*
 *
 */
 $("a#addNewCandidateButton").on("click", function() {

  alert("#addNewCandidateButton clicked.");//check


  var previousFieldset = $(this).parent(".row").prevAll("fieldset.wrapper:first");
  //alert(previousFieldset[0].outerHTML);//check


  var fieldsetToClone = previousFieldset.clone();
  //alert(fieldsetToClone[0].outerHTML);//check


  var idOfAddMobileButton = fieldsetToClone.find(".addMobileButton").attr('id');
  //alert('idOfAddMobileButton: ' + idOfAddMobileButton);

  var candidateNumber = idOfAddMobileButton.slice(idOfAddMobileButton.length-2, idOfAddMobileButton.length-1);
  //alert("candidateNumber: " + candidateNumber);//check
  var candidateNumberIncremented = ++candidateNumber;
  //alert('candidateNumberIncremented: ' + candidateNumberIncremented);//check



  fieldsetToClone.find('input[type=text]').each(function(index) {
   var inputNameAttribute = $(this).attr('name');
   //alert('inputNameAttribute: ' + inputNameAttribute);//check

   var indexOfFirstOpeningBracket = inputNameAttribute.indexOf('[');
   //alert('indexOfFirstOpeningBracket: ' + indexOfFirstOpeningBracket);//check

   var indexOfFirstClosingBracket = inputNameAttribute.indexOf(']');
   //alert('indexOfFirstClosingBracket') + indexOfFirstClosingBracket;//check


   var inputNameAttributeArray = inputNameAttribute.split('');
   //alert('inputNameAttributeArray: ' + inputNameAttributeArray);//check

   //inputNameAttributeArray.splice(indexOfFirstOpeningBracket, indexOfFirstClosingBracket, candidateNumberIncremented);
   var lengthOfCandidate = (indexOfFirstClosingBracket - indexOfFirstOpeningBracket) -1;
   //alert('lengthOfCandidate: ' + lengthOfCandidate);//check
   inputNameAttributeArray.splice((indexOfFirstOpeningBracket+1), lengthOfCandidate, candidateNumberIncremented);
   //alert('inputNameAttributeArray after SPLICING:' + inputNameAttributeArray);//check

   inputNameAttributeModified = inputNameAttributeArray.join('');
   //alert('inputNameAttributeModified: ' + inputNameAttributeModified);//check

   $(this).attr('name', inputNameAttributeModified);

  });



  fieldsetToClone = fieldsetToClone.prepend('<div class="container"><div class="divider"></div></div>');



  fieldsetToClone = fieldsetToClone.find("input[type=text]").val('');

  previousFieldset.after(fieldsetToClone);

 });
 


});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.99.0/js/materialize.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.99.0/css/materialize.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>




<form id="credentialsForm" action="" method="get">

 <fieldset class="container wrapper">
  <div class="row valign-wrapper">

   <div class="input-field col l3 offset-l1">
    <input type="text" id="nameInput0" class="validate" name="allCandidatesArray[0][nameInput]"/>
    <label class="blue-text" for="nameInput0">Name</label>
   </div>

   <div class="input-field col l3 offset-l1">
    <input type="text" id="ssnValueInput0" class="validate" name="allCandidatesArray[0][ssnValueInput]"/>
    <label class="blue-text" for="ssnValueInput0">SSN</label>
   </div>

  </div><!--.row-->



  <div class="row valign-wrapper">

   <div class="input-field col l3">
    <input type="text" id="mobileInput0" class="validate" name="allCandidatesArray[0][mobileInput][]"/>
    <label class="blue-text" for="mobileInput0">Mobile</label>
   </div>

   <div class="col l1 offset-l1 addMobileButtonWrapper">
    <a id="addMobileButton00" class="btn-floating btn waves-light waves-effect blue white-text addMobileButton"><i class="material-icons">add</i></a>
   </div>

  </div><!--.row-->



  <!--<div class="container"><div class="divider"></div></div>-->

  </fieldset><!--#wrapper-->






  <div class="row valign-wrapper">
   <a id="addNewCandidateButton" class="btn-flat waves-effect waves-light blue white-text col l2">Add Candidate</a>
  </div><!--.row-->


  

  <div class="row" id="submitFormRow">
   <div class="col l4 offset-l4">
    <button type="submit" class="btn waves-light waves-effect">Add Candidates</button>
   </div>
  </div><!--.row #s -->

</form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are overwriting cloned object in the following statements thus only inputs are appended.

```
fieldsetToClone = fieldsetToClone.prepend('<div class="container"><div class="divider"></div></div>');
fieldsetToClone = fieldsetToClone.find("input[type=text]").val('');
```

*Use*

```
fieldsetToClone.prepend('<div class="container"><div class="divider"></div></div>');
fieldsetToClone.find("input[type=text]").val('');
```

```js
$(document).on("click", ".addMobileButton", function() {
  var parentRow = $(this).closest(".row");
  var idOfThis = $(this).attr('id');
  var candidateNumber = idOfThis.slice(idOfThis.length - 2, idOfThis.length - 1);
  var nthMobileNumberOfThisCandidate = idOfThis.slice(-1);
  var newNthMobileOfThiscandidate = ++nthMobileNumberOfThisCandidate;
  parentRow.after('<div id="rowAddedForCandidatesMobile" class="row valign-wrapper"><div class="input-field col l3"><input type="text" id="mobileInput' + candidateNumber + '" class="validate" name="allCandidatesArray[' + candidateNumber + '][mobileInput][]"/><label for="mobileInput' + candidateNumber + '">Mobile</label></div><div class="col l1 addMobileButtonWrapper"><a id="addMobileButton' + candidateNumber + '' + newNthMobileOfThisCandidate + '" class="btn-floating btn waves-light waves-effect blue white-text addMobileButton"><i class="material-icons">add</i></a></div></div>');
});

$("a#addNewCandidateButton").on("click", function() {

  var previousFieldset = $(this).parent(".row").prevAll("fieldset.wrapper:first");
  var fieldsetToClone = previousFieldset.clone();
  var idOfAddMobileButton = fieldsetToClone.find(".addMobileButton").attr('id');
  var candidateNumber = idOfAddMobileButton.slice(idOfAddMobileButton.length - 2, idOfAddMobileButton.length - 1);

  var candidateNumberIncremented = ++candidateNumber;
  fieldsetToClone.find('input[type=text]').each(function(index) {
    var inputNameAttribute = $(this).attr('name');

    var indexOfFirstOpeningBracket = inputNameAttribute.indexOf('[');

    var indexOfFirstClosingBracket = inputNameAttribute.indexOf(']');

    var inputNameAttributeArray = inputNameAttribute.split('');
    var lengthOfCandidate = (indexOfFirstClosingBracket - indexOfFirstOpeningBracket) - 1;

    inputNameAttributeArray.splice((indexOfFirstOpeningBracket + 1), lengthOfCandidate, candidateNumberIncremented);

    inputNameAttributeModified = inputNameAttributeArray.join('');
    $(this).attr('name', inputNameAttributeModified);
  });

  fieldsetToClone.prepend('<div class="container"><div class="divider"></div></div>');

  fieldsetToClone.find("input[type=text]").val('');
  previousFieldset.after(fieldsetToClone);

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.99.0/js/materialize.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.99.0/css/materialize.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />




<form id="credentialsForm" action="" method="get">

  <fieldset class="container wrapper">
    <div class="row valign-wrapper">

      <div class="input-field col l3 offset-l1">
        <input type="text" id="nameInput0" class="validate" name="allCandidatesArray[0][nameInput]" />
        <label class="blue-text" for="nameInput0">Name</label>
      </div>

      <div class="input-field col l3 offset-l1">
        <input type="text" id="ssnValueInput0" class="validate" name="allCandidatesArray[0][ssnValueInput]" />
        <label class="blue-text" for="ssnValueInput0">SSN</label>
      </div>

    </div>
    <!--.row-->



    <div class="row valign-wrapper">

      <div class="input-field col l3">
        <input type="text" id="mobileInput0" class="validate" name="allCandidatesArray[0][mobileInput][]" />
        <label class="blue-text" for="mobileInput0">Mobile</label>
      </div>

      <div class="col l1 offset-l1 addMobileButtonWrapper">
        <a id="addMobileButton00" class="btn-floating btn waves-light waves-effect blue white-text addMobileButton"><i class="material-icons">add</i></a>
      </div>

    </div>
    <!--.row-->



    <!--<div class="container"><div class="divider"></div></div>-->

  </fieldset>
  <!--#wrapper-->






  <div class="row valign-wrapper">
    <a id="addNewCandidateButton" class="btn-flat waves-effect waves-light blue white-text col l2">Add Candidate</a>
  </div>
  <!--.row-->




  <div class="row" id="submitFormRow">
    <div class="col l4 offset-l4">
      <button type="submit" class="btn waves-light waves-effect">Add Candidates</button>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!--.row #s -->

</form>
```